# Is there a squence to use 'just as'

Tags: prepositions

> The accident happened **just as** the bus crossed the causeway.

or

> The bus crossed the causeway **just as** the accident happened.

May I know which one is correct?

Comment: Was the bus in the accident?

Comment: No.  Do ypu mean that this two sentences have two different meaning?

Comment: If you are only meaning that the two events occurred at the same time, with no interaction, then there is no difference.

Answer (score 1):

They both mean the same thing. I can imagine that some people might prefer one or the other in some situations, but there is never a situation where it would be *wrong* to use either of them.